# Typescript modules export/import confusion

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have those three files:

moduleA.ts:

```
export const foo = 42;
```

moduleB.ts:

```
module TestModules {
  export const bar = 43;
}
```

moduleC.ts:

```
import './moduleA';

module TestModules {
  console.log(TestModules.bar);
}
```

When I try to compile, I get a `moduleC.ts(4,29): error TS2339: Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'typeof TestModules'.` error.

Why?

I know mixing namespaces and modules ain't great but what if I have an old-style TypeScript project of a considerable size and I want to start using ES6-style modules?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's explained in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/909 .

TL;DR: Don't mix internal and external modules. It doesn't work.

Which sucks bad for older projects: they're pretty much stuck with internal modules or else - good luck refactoring.